# Python compiler for simple language to java vm code algorithm

Tags: python, compiler-construction, jvm, jvm-languages

I have a simple language that I am trying to write a compiler for (yes it is homework) to compile a simple language I shall describe if necessary to java vm code.

It currently works pretty well I've just hit a bump with logical AND's and OR's.

Each work fine in a single if/while condition, but if I try and chain them things go wrong, correct me if I am wrong but I believe that AND has precedence, but I was wondering if there are logical ways of arranging them? I think is what I'm trying to ask, the java vm code output just has the compare and jump statements one after the other (which seems wrong). I realise it's quite abstract so maybe what I'm after is a pseudo code/algorithm for how to structure chained AND's and OR's.

**EDIT**: Currently just treats any combination of AND and OR as AND's.  Comparing the factor/term/expression connection (compared to booleanfactor etc) I believe that AND has precedence? Just a thought.

Apologies if this is poorly understood :/

So i figure ill include relevant info just incase.

compiler

```
import re
import sys

# Restrictions:
# Integer constants must be short.
# Stack size must not exceed 1024.
# Integer is the only type.
# Logical operators cannot be nested.

class Scanner:
    '''The interface comprises the methods lookahead and consume.
       Other methods should not be called from outside of this class.'''

    def __init__(self, input_file):
        '''Reads the whole input_file to input_string.'''
        # source code of the program to be compiled
        self.input_string = input_file.read()
        # index where the unprocessed part of input_string starts
        self.current_char_index = 0
        # a pair (most recently read token, matched substring of input_string)
        self.current_token = self.get_token()

    def skip_white_space(self):
        '''Consumes all characters in input_string up to the next
           non-white-space character.'''
        if (self.current_char_index >= len(self.input_string) - 1):
            # bad fix for it over-running the end of the file
            return

        while self.input_string[self.current_char_index].isspace():
            self.current_char_index += 1


        return

    def get_token(self):
        '''Returns the next token and the part of input_string it matched.
           Returns None if there is no next token.
           The characters up to the end of the token are consumed.'''

        self.skip_white_space()
        # find the longest prefix of input_string that matches a token
        token, longest = None, ''
        for (t, r) in Token.token_regexp:
            match = re.match(r, self.input_string[self.current_char_index:])
            if match and match.end() > len(longest):
                token, longest = t, match.group()
        # consume the token by moving the index to the end of the matched part
        self.current_char_index += len(longest)
        return (token, longest)

    def lookahead(self):
        '''Returns the next token without consuming it.
           Returns None if there is no next token.'''
        return self.current_token[0]

    def consume(self, *tokens):
        '''Returns the next token and consumes it, if it is in tokens.
           Raises an exception otherwise.
           If the token is a number or an identifier, its value is returned.'''
        if self.current_token[0] not in tokens:
            print('Token ' + self.current_token[0] + ' isn\'t in the tokens: ')
            for token in tokens:
                print(token)
            raise Exception('Token is not in tokens this shouldn\'t happen much')

        if self.current_token[0] == 'ID':
            symbol_table.location(self.current_token[1])
            value = self.current_token[1]


        elif (self.current_token[0] == 'NUM'):
            value = self.current_token[1]

        else:
            value = self.current_token[0]

        self.current_token = self.get_token()

        return value



class Token:
    DO    = 'DO';
    ELSE  = 'ELSE';
    END   = 'END';
    IF    = 'IF';
    THEN  = 'THEN';
    WHILE = 'WHILE';
    SEM   = 'SEM';
    BEC   = 'BEC';
    LESS  = 'LESS';
    EQ    = 'EQ';
    GRTR  = 'GRTR';
    LEQ   = 'LEQ';
    NEQ   = 'NEQ';
    GEQ   = 'GEQ';
    ADD   = 'ADD';
    SUB   = 'SUB';
    MUL   = 'MUL';
    DIV   = 'DIV';
    LPAR  = 'LPAR';
    RPAR  = 'RPAR';
    NUM   = 'NUM';
    ID    = 'ID';
    READ  = 'READ';
    WRITE = 'WRITE';
    OR    = 'OR';
    AND   = 'AND';
    NOT   = 'NOT';


    # The following list gives the regular expression to match a token.
    # The order in the list matters for mimicking Flex behaviour.
    # Longer matches are preferred over shorter ones.
    # For same-length matches, the first in the list is preferred.
    token_regexp = [
        (DO,    'do'),
        (ELSE,  'else'),
        (END,   'end'),
        (IF,    'if'),
        (THEN,  'then'),
        (WHILE, 'while'),
        (READ,  'read'),
        (WRITE, 'write'),
        (OR,    'or'),
        (AND,   'and'),
        (NOT,   'not'),        
        (SEM,   ';'),
        (BEC,   ':='),
        (LESS,  '<'),
        (EQ,    '='),
        (NEQ,   '!='),
        (GRTR,  '>'),
        (LEQ,   '<='),
        (GEQ,   '>='),
        (ADD,   '[+]'), # + is special in regular expressions
        (SUB,   '-'),
        (MUL,   '[*]'),
        (DIV,   '/'),
        (LPAR,  '[(]'), # ( is special in regular expressions
        (RPAR,  '[)]'), # ) is special in regular expressions
        (ID,    '[a-z]+'),
        (NUM,   '[0-9]+'),
    ]

class Symbol_Table:
    '''A symbol table maps identifiers to locations.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.symbol_table = {}
    def size(self):
        '''Returns the number of entries in the symbol table.'''
        return len(self.symbol_table)
    def location(self, identifier):
        '''Returns the location of an identifier. If the identifier is not in
           the symbol table, it is entered with a new location. Locations are
           numbered sequentially starting with 0.'''
        if identifier in self.symbol_table:
            return self.symbol_table[identifier]
        index = len(self.symbol_table)
        self.symbol_table[identifier] = index
        return index

class Label:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_label = 0
    def next(self):
        '''Returns a new, unique label.'''
        self.current_label += 1
        return 'l' + str(self.current_label)

def indent(s, level):
    return '    '*level + s + '\n'

# Each of the following classes is a kind of node in the abstract syntax tree.
# indented(level) returns a string that shows the tree levels by indentation.
# code() returns a string with JVM bytecode implementing the tree fragment.
# true_code/false_code(label) jumps to label if the condition is/is not true.
# Execution of the generated code leaves the value of expressions on the stack.

class Program_AST:
    def __init__(self, program):
        self.program = program
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.program)
    def indented(self, level):
        return self.program.indented(level)
    def code(self):
        program = self.program.code()
        local = symbol_table.size()
        java_scanner = symbol_table.location('Java Scanner')
        return '.class public Program\n' + \
               '.super java/lang/Object\n' + \
               '.method public <init>()V\n' + \
               'aload_0\n' + \
               'invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V\n' + \
               'return\n' + \
               '.end method\n' + \
               '.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V\n' + \
               '.limit locals ' + str(local) + '\n' + \
               '.limit stack 1024\n' + \
               'new java/util/Scanner\n' + \
               'dup\n' + \
               'getstatic java/lang/System.in Ljava/io/InputStream;\n' + \
               'invokespecial java/util/Scanner.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V\n' + \
               'astore ' + str(java_scanner) + '\n' + \
               program + \
               'return\n' + \
               '.end method\n'

class Statements_AST:
    def __init__(self, statements):
        self.statements = statements
    def __repr__(self):
        result = repr(self.statements[0])
        for st in self.statements[1:]:
            result += '; ' + repr(st)
        return result
    def indented(self, level):
        result = indent('Statement(s)', level)
        for st in self.statements:
            result += st.indented(level+1)
        return result
    def code(self):
        result = ''
        for st in self.statements:
            result += st.code()
        return result

class If_AST:
    def __init__(self, boolean_expression, then):
        self.boolean_expression = boolean_expression
        self.then = then
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'if ' + repr(self.boolean_expression) + ' then ' + \
                       repr(self.then) + ' end'
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent('If-Then', level) + \
               self.boolean_expression.indented(level+1) + \
               self.then.indented(level+1)
    def code(self):
        l1 = label_generator.next()
        return self.boolean_expression.code(l1) + \
               self.then.code() + \
               l1 + ':\n'

class If_Else_AST:
    def __init__(self, boolean_expression, then, _else):
        self.boolean_expression = boolean_expression;
        self.then = then;
        self._else = _else;
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'if ' + repr(self.boolean_expression) + ' then ' + \
                       repr(self.then) + ' else ' + \
                       repr(self._else) + ' end'
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent('If-Then-Else', level) + \
               self.boolean_expression.indented(level+1) + \
               self.then.indented(level+1) + \
               indent('Else', level+1) + \
               self._else.indented(level+1)
    def code(self):
        l1 = label_generator.next()   
        l2 = label_generator.next()
        return self.boolean_expression.code(l1) + \
               self.then.code() + \
               'goto ' + l2 + '\n' + \
               l1 + ':\n' + \
               self._else.code() + \
               l2 + ':\n'


class While_AST:
    def __init__(self, boolean_term, body):
        self.boolean_term = boolean_term
        self.body = body
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'while ' + repr(self.boolean_term) + ' do ' + \
                          repr(self.body) + ' end'
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent('While-Do', level) + \
               self.boolean_term.indented(level+1) + \
               self.body.indented(level+2)
    def code(self):
        l1 = label_generator.next()
        l2 = label_generator.next()
        return l1 + ':\n' + \
               self.boolean_term.code(l2) + \
               self.body.code() + \
               'goto ' + l1 + '\n' + \
               l2 + ':\n'

class Assign_AST:
    def __init__(self, identifier, expression):
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.expression = expression
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.identifier) + ':=' + repr(self.expression)
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent('Assign', level) + \
               self.identifier.indented(level+1) + \
               self.expression.indented(level+1)
    def code(self):
        loc = symbol_table.location(self.identifier.identifier)
        return self.expression.code() + \
               'istore ' + str(loc) + '\n'

class Write_AST:
    def __init__(self, expression):
        self.expression = expression
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'write ' + repr(self.expression)
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent('Write', level) + self.expression.indented(level+1)
    def code(self):
        return 'getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;\n' + \
               self.expression.code() + \
               'invokestatic java/lang/String/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/String;\n' + \
               'invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V\n'

class Read_AST:
    def __init__(self, identifier):
        self.identifier = identifier
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'read ' + repr(self.identifier)
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent('Read', level) + self.identifier.indented(level+1)
    def code(self):
        java_scanner = symbol_table.location('Java Scanner')
        loc = symbol_table.location(self.identifier.identifier)
        return 'aload ' + str(java_scanner) + '\n' + \
               'invokevirtual java/util/Scanner.nextInt()I\n' + \
               'istore ' + str(loc) + '\n'

class Comparison_AST:
    def __init__(self, left, op, right):
        self.left = left
        self.op = op
        self.right = right
    def __repr__(self):
        op = { Token.LESS:'<', Token.EQ:'=', Token.GRTR:'>',
               Token.LEQ:'<=', Token.NEQ:'!=', Token.GEQ:'>=' }
        return repr(self.left) + op[self.op] + repr(self.right)
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent(self.op, level) + \
               self.left.indented(level+1) + \
               self.right.indented(level+1)
    def true_code(self, label):
        op = { Token.LESS:'if_icmplt', Token.EQ:'if_icmpeq',
               Token.GRTR:'if_icmpgt', Token.LEQ:'if_icmple',
               Token.NEQ:'if_icmpne', Token.GEQ:'if_icmpge' }
        return self.left.code() + \
               self.right.code() + \
               op[self.op] + ' ' + label + '\n'
    def false_code(self, label):
        # Negate each comparison because of jump to "false" label.
        op = { Token.LESS:'if_icmpge', Token.EQ:'if_icmpne',
               Token.GRTR:'if_icmple', Token.LEQ:'if_icmpgt',
               Token.NEQ:'if_icmpeq', Token.GEQ:'if_icmplt' }
        return self.left.code() + \
               self.right.code() + \
               op[self.op] + ' ' + label + '\n'

class Expression_AST:
    def __init__(self, left, op, right):
        self.left = left
        self.op = op
        self.right = right
    def __repr__(self):
        op = { Token.ADD:'+', Token.SUB:'-', Token.MUL:'*', Token.DIV:'/' }
        return '(' + repr(self.left) + op[self.op] + repr(self.right) + ')'
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent(self.op, level) + \
               self.left.indented(level+1) + \
               self.right.indented(level+1)
    def code(self):
        op = { Token.ADD:'iadd', Token.SUB:'isub',
               Token.MUL:'imul', Token.DIV:'idiv' }
        return self.left.code() + \
               self.right.code() + \
               op[self.op] + '\n'

class Number_AST:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.number
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent(self.number, level)
    def code(self): # works only for short numbers
        return 'sipush ' + self.number + '\n'

class Identifier_AST:
    def __init__(self, identifier):
        self.identifier = identifier
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.identifier
    def indented(self, level):
        return indent(self.identifier, level)
    def code(self):
        loc = symbol_table.location(self.identifier)
        return 'iload ' + str(loc) + '\n'

class BooleanFactor_AST:
    def __init__(self, condition, logic):
        self.condition = condition
        self.logic = logic
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.logic == False:
            return 'NOT ' + repr(self.condition)
        else:
            return repr(self.condition)
    def indented(self, level):
        if self.logic == False:
            return indent('NOT ', level) + self.condition.indented(level + 1)
        else:
            return self.condition.indented(level)
    def false_code(self, label):
        if self.logic == True:
            return self.condition.false_code(label)
        else:
            return self.condition.true_code(label)
        return
    def true_code(self, label):
        if self.logic == True:
            return self.condition.true_code(label)
        else:
            return self.condition.false_code(label)


class BooleanTerm_AST:
    def __init__(self, terms):
        self.terms = terms
    def __repr__(self):
        result = repr(self.terms[0])
        for term in self.terms[1:]:
            result = result + ' AND ' + repr(term)
        return result
    def indented(self, level):
        result = self.terms[0].indented(level)
        for term in self.terms[1:]:
            result = result + indent('AND', level)
            result = result + term.indented(level)
        return result
    def code(self, label):
        result = ''
        for term in self.terms:
            result = result + term.false_code(label)
        return result

class BooleanExpression_AST:
    def __init__(self, expressions):
        self.expressions = expressions
    def __repr__(self):
        result = repr(self.expressions[0])
        for expression in self.expressions[1:]:
            result = result + ' OR ' + repr(expression)
        return result
    def indented(self, level):
        result = self.expressions[0].indented(level)
        indentation = 0
        for expression in self.expressions[1:]:
            indentation += 1
            result = result + indent('OR', level + indentation)
            result = result + expression.indented(level + indentation)
        return result
    def code(self, label):
        result = ''
        for expression in self.expressions:
            result = result + expression.code(label)
        return result


# The following methods comprise the recursive-descent parser.

def program():
    sts = statements()
    return Program_AST(sts)

def statements():
    result = [statement()]
    while scanner.lookahead() == Token.SEM:
        scanner.consume(Token.SEM)
        st = statement()
        result.append(st)
    return Statements_AST(result)

def statement():
    if scanner.lookahead() == Token.IF:
        return if_statement()
    elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.WHILE:
        return while_statement()
    elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.ID:
        return assignment()
    elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.READ:
        return read();
    elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.WRITE:
        return write();
    else: # error
        return scanner.consume(Token.IF, Token.WHILE, Token.ID)

def if_statement():
    scanner.consume(Token.IF)
    condition = boolean_expression()
    scanner.consume(Token.THEN)
    then = statements()
    if scanner.lookahead() == Token.END:
        scanner.consume(Token.END)
        return If_AST(condition, then)
    else:
        scanner.consume(Token.ELSE)
        _else = statements()
        scanner.consume(Token.END)
        return If_Else_AST(condition, then, _else)

def while_statement():
    scanner.consume(Token.WHILE)
    condition = boolean_expression()
    scanner.consume(Token.DO)
    body = statements()
    scanner.consume(Token.END)
    return While_AST(condition, body)

def assignment():
    ident = identifier()
    scanner.consume(Token.BEC)
    expr = expression()
    return Assign_AST(ident, expr)

def read():
    scanner.consume(Token.READ)
    variable = identifier()
    return Read_AST(variable)


def write():
    scanner.consume(Token.WRITE)
    expr = expression()
    return Write_AST(expr)

def comparison():
    left = expression()
    op = scanner.consume(Token.LESS, Token.EQ, Token.GRTR,
                         Token.LEQ, Token.NEQ, Token.GEQ)
    right = expression()
    return Comparison_AST(left, op, right)

def expression():
    result = term()
    while scanner.lookahead() in [Token.ADD, Token.SUB]:
        op = scanner.consume(Token.ADD, Token.SUB)
        tree = term()
        result = Expression_AST(result, op, tree)
    return result

def term():
    result = factor()
    while scanner.lookahead() in [Token.MUL, Token.DIV]:
        op = scanner.consume(Token.MUL, Token.DIV)
        tree = factor()
        result = Expression_AST(result, op, tree)
    return result

def factor():
    if scanner.lookahead() == Token.LPAR:
        scanner.consume(Token.LPAR)
        result = expression()
        scanner.consume(Token.RPAR)
        return result
    elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.NUM:
        value = scanner.consume(Token.NUM)
        return Number_AST(value)
    elif scanner.lookahead() == Token.ID:
        return identifier()
    else: # error
        return scanner.consume(Token.LPAR, Token.NUM, Token.ID)

def identifier():
    value = scanner.consume(Token.ID)
    return Identifier_AST(value)

def boolean_factor():
    if scanner.lookahead() == Token.NOT:
        scanner.consume(Token.NOT)
        logic = False
    else:
        logic = True
    result = comparison()
    return BooleanFactor_AST(result, logic)

def boolean_term():
    result = [boolean_factor()]
    while scanner.lookahead() in [Token.AND]:
        scanner.consume(scanner.lookahead())
        temp = boolean_factor()
        result.append(temp)

    return BooleanTerm_AST(result)

def boolean_expression():
    result = [boolean_term()]
    while scanner.lookahead() in [Token.OR]:
        scanner.consume(scanner.lookahead())
        temp = boolean_term()
        result.append(temp)

    return BooleanExpression_AST(result)

# Initialise scanner, symbol table and label generator.

#scanner = Scanner(open('test.txt'))
scanner = Scanner(sys.stdin)
symbol_table = Symbol_Table()
symbol_table.location('Java Scanner') # fix a location for the Java Scanner
label_generator = Label()

# Uncomment the following to test the scanner without the parser.
# This shows a list of all tokens in the input.
#
#token = scanner.lookahead()

#while token != None:
#    print(token)
#    scanner.consume(token)
#    token = scanner.lookahead()

#exit()

# Call the parser.

ast = program()
assert scanner.lookahead() == None

# Uncomment the following to test the parser without the code generator.
# The first line gives back the program by calling __repr__ of the AST classes.
# The second line shows the syntax tree with levels indicated by indentation.
#
#print(ast)
#print(ast.indented(0))
#exit()

# Call the code generator.

# This translates the abstract syntax tree to JVM bytecode.
# It can be assembled to a class file by Jasmin: http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/

print(ast.code())
```

testing bat file

```
python compiler.py <test.txt> Program.j
java -Xmx100m -jar jasmin.jar Program.j
java -Xmx100m Program < testInput.txt > test_output.txt
```

and language (BNF)

```
Program = Statements
Statements = Statement (; Statement)
Statement = If | While | Assignment
If = if Comparison then Statements end
While = while Comparison do Statements end
Assignment = identifier := Expression
Comparison = Expression Relation Expression
Relation = = | != | < | <= | > | >=
Expression = Term ((+ | -) Term)
Term = Factor ((* | /) Factor)
Factor = (Expression) | number | identifier
BooleanExpression = BooleanTerm (or BooleanTerm)*
BooleanTerm = BooleanFactor (and BooleanFactor)*
BooleanFactor = not BooleanFactor | Comparison
```

I think thats all that is relevant, cheers if you take a go at helping me on this

Comment: eep, the j's in the language description are meant to be bitwise or's (|)

Comment: You can edit your question (click the gray `edit` button at the bottom of the post) if you want to fix that.

Comment: It was not clear to be if you were implementing a compiler for a specific language, but you said, "I believe that AND has precedence." A language may be defined so that AND or OR could have precedence; it depends entirely on the language's specification.

Comment: Oh ok, well I included the language definition so I guess that's for the best, what I was talking about with the precedence was python/c++ or rather other languages I've been using, so I agree probably not helpful but cheers for the input

Comment: Are they making you write all of this by hand? If not, I suggest you use some kind of tool to generate your scanners and parsers.

Comment: Not forcing per se but its all the learning experience that I'm after, but I guess if it gets too close to the deadline I may try that cheers

Comment: Assuming you've solved this, you could answer your own question, thus helping make SO better, and by earning you points, giving you more access to SO's features.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a method to chain OR's and AND'syou can use this property:

```
p v q === ¬p ^ ¬q
```

Is equivalent, you can process all in the **AND form**. for example.

```
p v q ^ r v s === ¬p ^ ¬q ^ ¬r ^ ¬s
```

So evaluate the expression in **AND form** is simple with an algorithm.

I guess the expression doesn't have any parenthesis, in other way you need prioritize the grouping symbols (), [], {}.